# $.each iterates only one object

Tags: php, jquery

All that I am trying is to iterate the data I have in the database using the `Jquery each` method, but couldn't figure when I am losing it all. Can someone look through this piece of code and tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
$(function(){

        var output = $("#folderOne");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://......',
            dataType: 'json',
            // data: {action: 'output'},
            success: function(data, status){
                console.log(data);    

                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    if (value.f_id == 1) {
                        var cards = "<div class='thumb'>" + value.f_id +
                        "</div><br>" + "<p>" + value.title + "</p> ";        
                    }
                    output.append(cards);

                });    
            },
```

Comment: what is the format of data? in console.log?

Comment: What's the output of the ` console.log(data);`?

Comment: irrespective of format , data always be a single variable never going to be array .. are you missing a parse to json object??

Comment: @RohitKumar that variable comment makes no sense and there is no need to parse when dataType is set

Comment: Probably there is only one element with `value.f_id == 1`, then only one card will be created. It is difficult to debug without the output of `console.log(data);`

Comment: Yep @charlietfl , but there is a still little confusion whether the server responing correct json ?? It need to be specified

Comment: @RohitKumar yes...that is very clear, however statement about never being array is wrong and needed to be corrected

Comment: cards var is local in if statement.

Comment: The consol.log returns the objects which were created and saved in the database 
 [Object, Object, Object]0: Object1: Object2: Objectlength: 3__proto__: Array[0]    @Akki619 I don't know why but it gives the same output when its before the parentesis and after the parentesis